# Spark badRecordsPath is not writing records to the Path as expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have a following sample csv data:

| id | name | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Raju" | 1000 |
| 2 | "Gautam" | 15000 |
| 3 | "Kishan" | 30000 |
| 4 | "Mike" | two hundread |

The salary field in last record is corrupted.

I am trying to handle the **corrupt record with badRecordsPath** as shown in the code below. But it is **not working**. I am using Spark 3.0.3, Scala 12 and Windows 10.

```scala
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType


object BadDataPathExample extends App{
  

  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
  
  
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  sparkConf.set("spark.app.name", "BadDataPathExample")
  sparkConf.set("spark.master", "local[2]")
  
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .config(sparkConf)
        .getOrCreate()
  

  val schema_string = "id int, name String, salary int"
  
  Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName).info(">> Starting to read Data")
  
  
  // read CSV
  val badDF = spark.read
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", true)
    .schema(schema_string)
    .option("badRecordsPath", "D:/spark_practice/bad_dir")
    .option("path", "D:/spark_practice/data/bad_emp.csv")
    .load
  
  badDF.show()
  badDF.printSchema()

}
```

The **Output from the above code** is as below:

[image]

As we can see that record is present with corrupted column value set to `Null`., which is coming from default behavior of "PERMISSIVE" mode. Also, there is no record being written to the bad records path specified.

But same code **works as expected in Databricks** as shown below.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Or is badRecordsPath a Databricks specific feature?

Comment: it seems a feature of databricks only as you said.

Comment: Yes.. Agreed, I had hunch after posting the question ... because you see in the highlighted output , bad records is stored as Parquet, while I had never specified the same .. only working with csv.

Answer (score 0):

`badRecordsPath` is only a Databricks specific feature.

We can see the logic in source code `FailureSafeParser`.

```scala
class FailureSafeParser[IN](
   
  def parse(input: IN): Iterator[InternalRow] = {
    try {
      rawParser.apply(input).toIterator.map(row => toResultRow(Some(row), () => null))
    } catch {
      case e: BadRecordException => mode match {
        case PermissiveMode =>
          Iterator(toResultRow(e.partialResult(), e.record))
        case DropMalformedMode =>
          Iterator.empty
        case FailFastMode =>
          throw QueryExecutionErrors.malformedRecordsDetectedInRecordParsingError(e)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

emmm...

I have a idea to refactor this code...

1. When there have `badRecordsPath` option, the `mode` forced to be `DropMalformedMode`  and ignore `mode` which user set.
2. `DropMalformedMode` parse rows with exception and write to `badRecordsPath`, then empty Iterator.